# ERROR: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected , org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions

Tags: oracle, spring-boot

this is the query that I'm using

```
            + Config.DB_SCHEMA_SERVICE+ ".EW_WALLET_OWNER o, "
            + Config.DB_SCHEMA_SERVICE+ ".EW_AGENT a, "
            + Config.DB_SCHEMA_SERVICE+ ".EW_WALLET_OWNER_CAT_TYPE t " +
            "where o.OWNER_ID = a.AGENT_ID and o.OWNER_TYPE_ID=1 and a.AGENT_LEVEL=1 and a.OWNER_CAT_ID=t.OWNER_CAT_ID and t.CAT_CODE='MERCHANT' and o.STATUS=1 order by ROWNUM asc", nativeQuery = true)
```

I'm getting below error and I couldn't identify what is wrong with the query

```
Mar 14, 2024 6:30:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

com.mmoney.merchantPayment.service.implementation.MerchNameListImpl | Error in System : org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select ROWNUM as 'rowNum', o.NAME as 'name', o.OWNER_ALIAS as 'ownerAlias' from MMONEY_SERVICE.EW_WALLET_OWNER o, MMONEY_SERVICE.EW_AGENT a, MMONEY_SERVICE.EW_WALLET_OWNER_CAT_TYPE t where o.OWNER_ID = a.AGENT_ID and o.OWNER_TYPE_ID=1 and a.AGENT_LEVEL=1 and a.OWNER_CAT_ID=t.OWNER_CAT_ID and t.CAT_CODE='MERCHANT' and o.STATUS=1 order by ROWNUM asc]; SQL [n/a]
```

Could You guys see what is the problem here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query you're running uses single quotes for column aliases; should've been **double** ones.

```
No : select ROWNUM as 'rowNum', o.NAME as 'name', o.OWNER_ALIAS as 'ownerAlias' from ...

Yes: select ROWNUM as "rowNum", o.NAME as "name", o.OWNER_ALIAS as "ownerAlias" from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle:

- `'` single quotes are used to surround text literals;
- Identifiers are either unquoted or surrounded by `"` double quotes (and are then case-sensitive).

  Using double-quotes is considered bad practice as it forces you to always use double quotes and case-sensitive identifiers. If possible, always use unquoted identifiers.

You are using `'` around identifiers when you should be using either no quotes or double-quotes. You do not actually need all of the aliases:

```sql
select ROWNUM,
       o.NAME,
       o.OWNER_ALIAS AS ownerAlias
from   MMONEY_SERVICE.EW_WALLET_OWNER o
       INNER JOIN MMONEY_SERVICE.EW_AGENT a
       ON o.OWNER_ID = a.AGENT_ID
       INNER JOIN MMONEY_SERVICE.EW_WALLET_OWNER_CAT_TYPE t
       ON a.OWNER_CAT_ID=t.OWNER_CAT_ID
where  o.OWNER_TYPE_ID=1
and    a.AGENT_LEVEL=1
and    t.CAT_CODE='MERCHANT'
and    o.STATUS=1
order by ROWNUM asc
```

But if you did want the case-sensitive identifiers then:

```sql
select ROWNUM AS "rowNum",
       o.NAME AS "name",
       o.OWNER_ALIAS AS "ownerAlias"
from   MMONEY_SERVICE.EW_WALLET_OWNER o
       INNER JOIN MMONEY_SERVICE.EW_AGENT a
       ON o.OWNER_ID = a.AGENT_ID
       INNER JOIN MMONEY_SERVICE.EW_WALLET_OWNER_CAT_TYPE t
       ON a.OWNER_CAT_ID=t.OWNER_CAT_ID
where  o.OWNER_TYPE_ID=1
and    a.AGENT_LEVEL=1
and    t.CAT_CODE='MERCHANT'
and    o.STATUS=1
order by "rowNum" asc
```